# Execute a shell script using execl in C program

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I am trying hard to run a simple shell script in my C Code

for simplicity I have erased everything else

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define SHELL "/bin/sh"
int main()
{


execl("/home/amir/Desktop/OSAssignment/script.sh","script.sh",NULL);



        return 0;
}
```

my C program and script.sh both are located in Desktop-> OSAssignment ->

I have compiled the program and executed it shows nothing (If I place a printf statement below or above exec command it gets successfully printed)
I have tried everything

Here's my Shell script file

```
echo "Hi"
```

Comment: ... and? If this does not work, then please [edit] your question and say so, along with any errors or warnings that may be produced when you try.

Comment: It's not working...

Comment: Well, something must be wrong then.  Unfortunately, you don't tell us what's happening.

Comment: How do you know it is not working? You forgot to test in your C program above that  `execl` didn't fail!

Comment: I have added my shell script file as well ...

Comment: @Kusalananda  It's not working because when I compile my code it should execute the shell file and hence should print hi

Comment: Make sure the script is executable and has a proper `#!`-line.

Comment: I forgot to add #! in it though it was executable (I used chmod +x script.sh) Thanks

Comment: "It's not working" is a useless statement. Say: "I compiled the program, executed the program, but my shell script did not get executed".

Comment: @JeffSchaller I understand, I thought by writing it's not working is more or less the same meaning. But, anyway thanks for your input. I have edited it so that others who are facing the same issue can get benefit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A script that is executed without an explicit interpreter must be executable and have a proper `#!`-line.

If there is no `#!`-line, or if it's not executable, you must execute the script with an interpreter, as in

```
sh /path/to/script.sh
```

You should also examine the return code from `execl()` to see if the call failed.  If it failed, you may use `perror()` to print an error message.  See the manual for `perror` on your system.

Answer (score 0):

Read documentation of [execl(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/execl.3.html) and [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) (which gets called by `execl`). They can fail (and that is the only way they can return; on success these functions don't return, since they are changing the entire virtual address space of their process).

So code (using [perror(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html)):

```
 execl("/home/amir/Desktop/OSAssignment/script.sh","script.sh",NULL);
 perror("execl script.sh");
```

You need to have your script executable, and you should start it with a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)). Its first line should be `#!/bin/sh`

Please read carefully the documentation of every function that you use.

Comment: what does perror tell?

Comment: what the documentation of [perror(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html) says?

Comment: Thanks. I have figured it out I wasn't using #!/bin/sh 
and perror tells me that no file exist